# Is there any way to reuse an old modem and possibly revive it?

Tags: drivers

I found an old [Hotwire 6205 ADSL Modem](http://www.user-manual.info/fr/431827/modem/paradyne/6205/3/) in my parent's room. It still works, as I confirmed from them and by plugging it in. Now, it does work with our current internet connection, however, I cannot find the driver for it. All that I can find in it's manual is that the driver is called Eagle II USB ADSL modem. I found an Ubuntu version, but I'm running Windows and my CPU hates Ubuntu. Also, sometimes when I plug it into a computer, for some reason, the WAN light blinks, meaning it is handshaking? I still have to find more about it.

My main question however, is can I turn it into a little server? I can connect it to a computer and then connect a SATA SSD to the computer, and the SSD being the storage and the modem handling everything else. Thank you for your time and patience, reading this question.

Comment: Can you extend on "everything else" ? According to the manual it is just a standard modem (not even a router) with a Line slot and a USB slot for the PC. How Can it communicate with other machines ?

Comment: Hi @user1459, This question is not about the 'Internet of things', it is a simple networking question. We don't have a clear page which explains this yet, but basically we're looking for questions about machine-to-machine communications (this is the 'things' in the title). You should ask your question on superuser.com

Comment: You can see a draft of the description here: http://meta.iot.stackexchange.com/questions/254/improving-the-guidance-in-the-help-center-for-new-users

Comment: In its current state this question is not a good fit for the site. If you do elaborate a bit on what you would want to do with that router that might change. If your goal is to just reactivate the modem, Superuser is likely a better fit. If you want to use it for specific IoT use cases you're welcome, but you have to detail your question if that is the case.

Answer (score 4):

**From an IoT point of view, the only thing I see is a temperature/light/intrusion Watch dog for an empty secondary house in a 4G non covered area (suburbs, countryside,...)**, hence I am waiting for more ideas from OP. But...

- I don't know where you live but in France every ADSL subscription comes with a "box" which behaves like a modem/router so you might already have one if your secondary house has an ADSL capable line.
- For surveillance or even just simple file sharing, a normal desktop is really overkill (100W power, noise, heat, too many components,...), just use a Raspberry Pi and [connect it to your modem](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=158088&p=1028515), then connect an external HDD and/or an IoT antenna (z-wave,...).
- If you intent to use your computer as a NAS for backups or more robust file sharing, I wouldn't let it alone plugged to the Internet especially if you have to use Windows because of the modem's drivers.
- ADSL/56k is no more standard way to connect to Internet, nowadays you can easily make a WIFI bridge with your phone or even buy an extra 4G SIM card from your ISP to do data. So if you are in an uncovered 4G zone, why not...

So...

- **You are better off buying a brand new modem/router with at least 4 Ethernet ports**
- As @SeanHoulihane says, you better ask [superuser SE](https://superuser.com/) if they have networking ideas in general

Comment: It might be better to clarify the questions scope first with a few pointed comments since the question is currently very open-ended and your answering effort might shoot past the target.